# Concatenando Objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte array javascript:

```
    for(var k in lista) {
            for(var x in lista[k]){
                var donutData = [
                    {label: x, data: lista[k][x], color: "#3c8dbc"}
                ];
            }
        }
```

Ao final gostaria que a variável donutData ficasse assim:

```
    var donutData = [
      {label: "Series2", data: 30, color: "#3c8dbc"},
      {label: "Series3", data: 20, color: "#F56954"},
      {label: "Series4", data: 50, color: "#00A65A"},
      {label: "Series4", data: 50, color: "#F39C12"},
      {label: "Series4", data: 50, color: "#00C0EF"}
    ];
```

É possível?

Comment: Sem saver a estrutura de `lista` é dificil ajudar. Testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/cw890hwc/ se não funcionar coloca a estrutura de `lista` na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código original está fazendo o seguinte:

- Iniciando um laço, `k`;
- Iniciando um sub-laço, `x`;
- Inicializando uma variável do tipo array, `donutData`;
- Populando `donutData` com um elemento via método `push()`.

Note que para todo ciclo de `k` e `x`, `donutData` é reinicializada - resultando assim em uma variável contendo apenas um elemento, sempre.

Para resolver seu problema, realoque a variável donutData, criando-a antes de iniciar os laços:

```
var donutData = [];

for(var k in lista) {
     for(var x in lista[k]){
         donutData.push({label: x, data: lista[k][x], color: "#3c8dbc"});
     }
 }
```

Assim o valor de `donutData` será preservado entre iterações dos laços.

Answer (score 2):

Deve usar [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para adicionar elementos a um array e não vale a pena estar sempre a inicializar a variável dentro do ciclo:

```
var donutData = [];
for(var k in lista) {
     for(var x in lista[k]){
         donutData.push({label: x, data: lista[k][x], color: "#3c8dbc"});
     }
 }
```

Isto partindo do príncipio que condiz com sua estrutura da varável lista.
Nota que assim não vais obter o resultado que pretendes, pelo menos no campo da `color`, que vai sempre o mesmo. Sem ver a `lista`, não sei onde ir buscar a côr dentro da `lista`.